# Checkbox cross mark alignment fix

Tags: css

I need to display a cross mark inside unchecked checkbox. I have written a code like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cls-1"/>
```

CSS:

```
.cls-1:not(:checked):after {
    content: '\00D7';
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
}
```

The alignment of cross-mark is not correct though. There appears a space between checkbox top and cross mark top. Is there a way to make cross mark appear exactly at center.

Stackblitz for sample code can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ul1sgb

Comment: can you not just margin top -1px? (or the amount you want)

Comment: Using pseudo elements on input elements only works in some browsers, and should not work at all in theory … this is something you should avoid.

Comment: @04FS Even if thats true this won't break interactivity for those browsers. Its just a little extra styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.cls-1:not(:checked):after {
  content: '\00D7';
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-2px;
}
.cls-1 {
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div id="app1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cls-1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: In future, if a checkbox `width`, `height` or `padding` will be change this approach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding a line-height property to the input type checkbox,
say 10px;
eg:

```
input {
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: flex; align-items: center;` in `.cls-1`. Thanks

```
.cls-1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your css to center the cross. Use line-height of 0.5rem to achieve this.

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.cls-1:not(:checked):after {
  content: '\00D7';
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  line-height: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="app1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cls-1"/>
</div>
```